# One centered colorbar below four image plots in R

Tags: r, graphics

I´m trying to get one centered colorbar for my four image plots. I did a Principal Component Analysis and got my first four components. These components are displayed or should be displayed in 2D grids, getting specific longitudes and latitudes. The colorbar I would like to produce should be represent the values of all four components and it should be centered under the last component. The code produces the wanted four plots, and now only the legend is missing.

My Code so far:

```
nlevel <- 64 
nc2$dim$lon$vals -> lon 
nc2$dim$lat$vals -> lat 
par(mfrow = c(4,1)) 
image(lon,lat,xMat1, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latiitude", col = tim.colors(level)) 
image(lon,lat,xMat2, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latiitude", col = tim.colors(level)) 
image(lon,lat,xMat3, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latiitude", col = tim.colors(level)) 
image(lon,lat,xMat4, xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latiitude", col = tim.colors(level))
```

xMat 1-4 is here the matrix of the values of the several principal components. Numbers 1-4 are the several components.

Are there any advices?

Thanks in advance!